# pybind11 and conversion of complex type

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am in the process of transferring an algebra system from boost/python to pybind11 and most of it works fine and only requires an easy modification. This system also implements complex versions of its types where the real and imaginary component are **not numeric types** (think polynomials or Fourier series).

Everywhere in the documentation I read to include pybind11/complex.h if I want to do this (e.g. chapter 11.1 of the documentation). My problem with this is now that when I do this the compilation fails. This failure happens in the attempt to bind a method to python that in some form returns an object of the complex type.
If I don't include 'pybind11/complex11' the compilation goes fine and the methods work fine but some of my tests, when trying to construct such an object from a python complex (e.g. (1+0j) ), fail. It complains that no corresponding constructor is defined despite the fact that there is constructors of the types AC(complex),AC(AC), and others implemented and made visible via 'def(pybind11::init)'.

Here is a simple example where the compilation failure can be seen.

```
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"
#include "pybind11/complex.h"
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>


class A {

};


template <typename T>
T copy(T& x)
{
    return T(x);
}


using AC = std::complex<A>;


PYBIND11_MODULE(TESTA, m)
{
    pybind11::class_<AC> inst(m, "AC", "test for AC");
    inst.def(pybind11::init<>());
    inst.def("__copy__", &copy<AC>);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

With the result:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Pybindtest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Pybindtest.cpp
1>C:\Python38\include\pybind11\complex.h(59,1): error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from '_Ty' to 'double'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=A
1>        ]
1>C:\Python38\include\pybind11\complex.h(59,38): message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>C:\Python38\include\pybind11\complex.h(58): message : while compiling class template member function 'pybind11::handle pybind11::detail::type_caster<std::complex<A>,void>::cast(const std::complex<A> &,pybind11::return_value_policy,pybind11::handle)'
1>C:\Python38\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(159): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'pybind11::handle pybind11::detail::type_caster<std::complex<A>,void>::cast(const std::complex<A> &,pybind11::return_value_policy,pybind11::handle)' being compiled
1>C:\Python38\include\pybind11\cast.h(1946): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'pybind11::detail::type_caster<std::complex<A>,void>' being compiled
1>C:\Python38\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(100): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'pybind11::detail::argument_loader<T &>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=AC
1>        ]
1>C:\Python38\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(63): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void pybind11::cpp_function::initialize<Return(__cdecl *&)(T &),Return,T&,pybind11::name,pybind11::is_method,pybind11::sibling>(Func,Return (__cdecl *)(T &),const pybind11::name &,const pybind11::is_method &,const pybind11::sibling &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Return=AC,
1>            T=AC,
1>            Func=AC (__cdecl *&)(AC &)
1>        ]
1>C:\Python38\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1117): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<T,T&,pybind11::name,pybind11::is_method,pybind11::sibling>(Return (__cdecl *)(T &),const pybind11::name &,const pybind11::is_method &,const pybind11::sibling &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=AC,
1>            Return=AC
1>        ]
1>D:\temp for tests\Pybindtest\Pybindtest.cpp(29): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'pybind11::class_<AC> &pybind11::class_<AC>::def<T(__cdecl *)(T &),>(const char *,Func &&)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=AC,
1>            Func=AC (__cdecl *)(AC &)
1>        ]
1>D:\temp for tests\Pybindtest\Pybindtest.cpp(29): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'pybind11::class_<AC> &pybind11::class_<AC>::def<T(__cdecl *)(T &),>(const char *,Func &&)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=AC,
1>            Func=AC (__cdecl *)(AC &)
1>        ]
1>C:\Python38\include\pybind11\complex.h(59,1): error C2660: 'PyComplex_FromDoubles': function does not take 1 arguments
1>C:\Python38\include\complexobject.h(47,24): message : see declaration of 'PyComplex_FromDoubles'
1>Done building project "Pybindtest.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I know that it tells me about missing conversion etc. but I also don't want to convert anything to double. It should, in the above case, be converted to A and I thought that's what the inclusion of 'pybind11/complex.h' was supposed to do.

Most likely I am doing something wrong or I am missing something.
Any suggestions?

Thanks
Hartmuth

Comment: I don't think pybind11 supports what you want. You may look at `pybind11/complex.h`, it has `std::is_floating_point<T>` everywhere. You mat want to try writing your own version of this that is not tied to floating point types.

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m: That is one thing I was wondering. In that case the documentation is actually misleading. For std::complex<T> it doesn't mention anything for T of being a numeric type only. Interestingly boost/python doesn't have a problem with the situation.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex "The effect of instantiating the template complex for any other type is unspecified".

Comment: That is a rather interesting statement that I have not seem before. I have to contact the originator of the software if he is aware of that because there is a much modified and complete rewrite of that software existing that might use the same type of construction. Thanks for that reference.